# Gmail SMTP graceful login

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I'm using Gmail SMTP to send emails in Python, however sometimes the application may stay idle for an extended period of time.

How do I make sure that the session hasn't expired? Here's my code:

```
def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):
    import smtplib

    gmail_user = user
    gmail_pwd = pwd
    FROM = user
    TO = recipient if type(recipient) is list else [recipient]
    SUBJECT = subject
    TEXT = body

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
            server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
            server.close()
            print 'successfully sent the mail'
    except:
            print "failed to send mail"
```

Can I always reuse the server session, or can it expire after let's say 5 hours?

Comment: What server session you are referring? In your code you are creating a new object of `smtplib.SMTP` every time that the function send_mail is called. Use `server.quit()` instead of `server.close()` and considered use a try catch for capturing a specific exception `smtplib.SMTPException`, eg: network connection.

Comment: Please ignore the closing and most of the code. What I mean is, will Gmail log the account out due to inactivity? For example, I login, wait 5 hours and then try to send an email.

Comment: Considering that you are sending an e-mail programmatically, you should start a connection and send almost at same time. But you can see details about SMTP timeouts on [RFC2821](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821#section-4.5.3.2)

Comment: Isn't Gmail or other SMTP servers going to block repeated login attempts?

Comment: It depends! You can send 2000 emails daily for each account. See [here more instructions and other limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)